# Cannot copy tables from HR schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm not able to create copy tables of the HR schema in Oracle SQL Developer.

When I run the query - 
create table employees as `(SELECT * from HR.employees);`

I get the following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Maybe your user does not have access to see the table. See if the table exists : select * from sys.all_tables where owner = 'HR'

Comment: After I run the query, no records were shown in sys.all_tables indicating that the table does not exist. Thanks! However, shouldn't the HR schema tables already be installed when the database is created?

Comment: `all_tables` will only show the tables you have privs on, so that doesn't tell you if it exists, if you ran that as yourself. The schema may have been installed, you'd need to connect to it, or as a DBA, to grant the privs to your user.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have rights to select from that table AND/OR it does not exist.
Try

```
grant select on employees to your_user;
```

with the HR user.

Answer (score 0):

From sys DBA schema :

```
Grant SELECT on HR.employees to USER_NAME;
```

Or connect as HR and then

```
Grant SELECT on employees to USER_NAME;
```